# Why doesn't my image load on internet explorer browser?

Tags: html

Why doesn't my navigation bar logo on the far left hand corner of my name display on the browser internet explorer when I open the html web page?

Below is my html code for the navigation bar. I have ran the full website code with the same navigation bar code on and the two browsers chrome & Safari have successfully displayed the image. However, the browser internet explorer doesn't and I'm wondering how I can fix this?

**Navigation Bar Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a id="nav_a" class="navbar-brand pull-left" href=""><img id="nav_img" class="img-responsive" src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
               <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-center">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                  <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-xs ">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Homepage%20Section1-2.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%206.html">Unit 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%2014.html">Unit 14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%207.html">Unit 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%201.html">Unit 1</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/About%20Me.html">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/CV.html">CV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Education.html">Education</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
```

**FULL SITE CODE**

```css
      .nav-title {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 30px;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-left: 10px;
      }
      .contact-title {
      font-size: 20pt;
      color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-right: auto;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: 60px;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-left: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
      #linkbutton {
      text-align: center;
      border: none;
      background: lightgrey;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      .p1 {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-right: -25px;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .p2 {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-right: auto;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-left: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .anchorAwesome {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 99;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      top: 170px;
      left: -30px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .anchorAwesome2 {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 99;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      top: 500px;
      left: -30px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .anchorAwesome.FixPosition {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      }
      #contact-me {
      position: relative;
      }
      #nav_a {
      width: 40%;
      }
      #nav_img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translatex(-50%);
      }
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
      }
      .nav.navbar-nav,
      .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      }
      .section {
      min-height: 100vh;
      }
      .one {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .two {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      #sections .section {
      padding-top: 50px;
      }
      .hero {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38892/pexels-photo-38892.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 60%;
      }
      .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      border:2px solid white;
      background-image: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      background-size: contain;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
      }
      .fa-angle-down {
      color: black;
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      }
      .fa-angle-up {
      color: black;
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      }
      .s1-text {
      height: 20pt;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20pt;
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      z-index: 99;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 60px;
      top: 440px;
      left: 10px;
      right: 0px;
      }
      a {
      color: #337ab7;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 99999;
      }
      .moreMe {
      color: #337ab7;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      color: black;
      z-index: 99999;
      }
      .s2-text {
      height: 20pt;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      font-size: 20pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      z-index: 99;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      top: 470px;
      left: 10px;
      right: 0px;
      }
      .s3-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      z-index: 99;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      top: 715px;
      left: 5px;
      right: 0px;
      }
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
      #feedback-page {
      text-align: center;
      }
      #form-main {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      padding-top: 0px;
      }
      #form-div {
      background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-right: 25px;
      padding-top: 25px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      width: 550px;
      float: left;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-left: -270px;
      -moz-border-radius: 7px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
      }
      .feedback-input {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 0;
      text-align: left;
      color: black;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
      padding: 23px 23px 23px 74px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      }
      .feedback-input:focus {
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0;
      border: 3px solid #3498db;
      color: black;
      outline: none;
      padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
      }
      .focused {
      color: black;
      border: #30aed6 solid 3px;
      }
      .textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      line-height: 150%;
      resize: vertical;
      }
      .input:hover,
      textarea:hover,
      .input:focus,
      textarea:focus {
      background-color: white;
      }
      #button-blue {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color: black;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding-top: 22px;
      padding-bottom: 22px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      margin-top: -4px;
      font-weight: 700;
      }
      #button-blue:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      color: black;
      }
      .submit:hover {
      color: #3498db;
      }
      .ease {
      width: 0px;
      height: 74px;
      color: black;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
      -moz-transition: .3s ease;
      -o-transition: .3s ease;
      -ms-transition: .3s ease;
      transition: .3s ease;
      }
      .submit:hover .ease {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
      #form-div {
      left: 3%;
      margin-right: 3%;
      width: 88%;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 3%;
      padding-right: 3%;
      }
      }
      button {
      color: black;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a id="nav_a" class="navbar-brand pull-left" href=""><img id="nav_img" class="img-responsive" src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
               <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-center">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                  <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-xs ">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Homepage%20Section1-2.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%206.html">Unit 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%2014.html">Unit 14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%207.html">Unit 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Unit%201.html">Unit 1</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/About%20Me.html">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/CV.html">CV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/Education.html">Education</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="sections">
         <div class="section one" id="section_one">
            <div class="shape"></div>
            <div class="hero"></div>
            <div class="s1-text center-block">WELCOME TO MY</div>
            <div class="s2-text center-block">PORTFOLIO</div>
            <h1 class="s3-text center-block">CLICK ON THE ARROW TO GO TO THE CONTACT ME PAGE</h1>
            <div class="container text-center">
               <a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/About%20Me.html">
               <button class="moreMe">Click on this button to go to the "About Me" page</button>
               </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#contact-me" class="anchorAwesome"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
         </div>
         <div id="contact-me" class="section two">
            <h2 class="s3-text">CLICK ON THE ARROW UP TO SCROLL UP</h2>
            <h1 class="contact-title">Get in touch</h1>
            <p class="p1">Wanna get in touch or talk to me about a project?</p>
            <p class="p2">Fill the form below or send an email to ldocherty1@student.hackney.ac.uk.</p>
            <div id="form-main">
               <div id="form-div">
                  <form class="form" id="form1">
                     <div class="name">
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="email">
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                     </div>
                     <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                     <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" />
                        <div class="ease"></div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <a href="#section_one" class="anchorAwesome2"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#sections').fullpage();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with your CSS most likely, can we view that?

---

This issue resides here:

```
#nav_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
```

As far as I can see the logo only dissapears after a browser width of 768px in edge. Raising the height, or taking it to the default also shows the logo.

It seems like the `transform: translatex()` property is buggy in Edge/iExplorer.
Thus shifting it over.

I have seen other threads with this issue, suggesting to position it from the right instead of the left to overcome this.

Comment: Thanks for your post, when I get home I'll test it out.

Answer (score 0):

When browsing in IE if you open Developer tools (f12) and look at the path of the image, then browse to that path does the image appear? you can also change the CSS here, IE might be rendering he CSS different to other browsers so you can utilise the Dev. tools and see if the CSS is rendering properly.